# Return boolean value from Material UI Radio to use in Yup .when Validation

Tags: reactjs, validation, material-ui, yup

Yup allows for validation based on another value using `.when`.

Example:

```
var inst = yup.object({
  isBig: yup.boolean(),
  count: yup
    .number()
    .when('isBig', {
      is: true, // alternatively: (val) => val == true
      then: yup.number().min(5),
      otherwise: yup.number().min(0),
    })
});
```

Material UI's Radio forms only allow string values in `value` field.
Example:

```
<Radio
 checked={this.state.selectedValue === 'a'}
 onChange={this.handleChange}
 value="a"
 name="radio-button-demo"
 aria-label="A"
/>
```

Changing the value to: `value={true}` or anything other than a string breaks the Radio component.
Forcing the radio value in yup validation with `yup.boolean` does not help.

My alternative is switching to inline validation, which is not idea.

What I am trying to do: if `isBig` returns true, require count to be a number with a minimum of 5 digits, other wise ignore it.

What am I missing here? Is there a way to conditionally validate related values through yup using a check other then .when? Or, am I missing something in the Radio component that is obvious?

Appreciate any help, Yup examples online dont go far outside of what Yup documentation provides as examples.

Comment: I'm not understanding why it is an issue for the Radio value to be a string. yup works just fine with strings. It would help to see the code of how you use the schema returned by `yup.object`. Are you calling `inst.isValid(this.state)`? What object are you validating against the schema?

Comment: Your comment below explained everything. I was under the impression that yup `is` could only test boolean values, therefore I was trying to force a true/false on the Radio value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem to drive off of a string for the validation. Also `min(5)` doesn't mean a minimum of five digits, it means a number >= 5. For a min of 5 digits, you would need `min(10000)`.

Here's an example of using `when` on a string. If you go to the CodeSandbox, you'll see that `myForm1` is not valid (enforces the minimum of 10000 since "a" matches), but `myForm2` is valid since "b" doesn't match the condition.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as yup from "yup";

const myForm1 = {
  radioValue: "a",
  num: 1234
};
const myForm2 = {
  radioValue: "b",
  num: 1234
};
const schema = yup.object({
  radioValue: yup.string(),
  num: yup.number().when("radioValue", {
    is: "a",
    then: yup.number().min(10000),
    otherwise: yup.number().min(0)
  })
});

function App() {
  const [myForm1IsValid, setMyForm1IsValid] = useState(null);
  const [myForm2IsValid, setMyForm2IsValid] = useState(null);
  useEffect(async () => {
    setMyForm1IsValid(await schema.isValid(myForm1));
    setMyForm2IsValid(await schema.isValid(myForm2));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>myForm1 is valid: {JSON.stringify(myForm1IsValid)}</h1>
      <h1>myForm2 is valid: {JSON.stringify(myForm2IsValid)}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit yup]

Comment: Wow. Thank you Ryan - I didn't know you could pass in values other than `true`, `false` on the `is` validation. Worked perfectly.